# PHP for loop or array working on one server but not the other

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a script that just processes some checkboxes and deletes the ones that are checked.

The script just wouldnt work on my personal server running centos 5.5.  As soon as I swapped the script over to my dedicated server from hostgator, it worked fine without a change.  I am not sure if its the array or the loop.  When i try to print the array using print_r it just says "Array"

This is what i have after the form submit, the form consists of a list of checkboxes named delete[].  It's almost is the array is not working.

```
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {

        if(!empty($delete[$i])) {

            //database query here to delete the date
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check register_globals settings, and read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is, that on your dedicated server "register_globals" is on. try

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {

    if(!empty($_POST["delete"][$i])) {

        //database query here to delete the date
    }

}
```

But for security reasons you should check the contents of the array.

Comment: I would not stimulate the use of $_REQUEST.

Comment: Okay, may be $_POST is a bit more specific (edited my answer). But I mentioned to check the contents of this array.